# problem blocking TCP scans by setting up honeyd in virtual environment

Tags: ids, honeypot

I am creating a virtual environment where I have created three virtual machines,

- CentOS as an Apache Webserver
- CentOs as an Attacker machine
- FreeBSD with Honeyd to setup Honeypot

I have connected all three virtual machines in a same network, and installed honeyd in Attacker machine.

The IP of attacker is `192.168.154.100`
The IP of machine where honeyd is installed is `192.168.154.28`
The IP of honeypot that is created by `honeyd` is `192.168.154.22`
The IP of my Apache Webserver is `192.168.154.21`

Using Attacker machine I perform an `nmap` scan using the following command,

```
nmap 192.168.154.*
```

and `honeyd` successfully detected the attack.

But I have one problem, `honeyd` is installed in separate machine as Apache webserver. How can I block TCP scans from the attacker IP address to my webserver?

I installed a firewall in my Apache webserver virtual machine but how does my Apache machine know which IP are performing attacks so that I can block them?

Comment: I am very confused about your question. What does honeyd have to do with blocking IPs to your web server? Were you hoping to use honeyd as an IPS?

Comment: yes as an IDS, because that's what we are told to use. I need to block tcp scans to my apache web server which is in the same network as `honeyd`

Comment: You were told to use honeyd as an IPS and not snort (an actual IPS)? This question, then, is not an InfoSec question, per se, but rather a scripting question: "how to I export the IPs detected from honeyd to another machine".